# Using std::sort with a raw array of pointers?

Tags: c++, lambda

Let's say you have some older code and data structures:

```
struct TEST
{
   int a;
   int b;
};

TEST *items[9]; // Points to an array of TEST*
```

Now I want to sort these objects. Old code uses QSort, but I want to use std::sort. What would this look like?

I tried something like:

```
typedef std::function<bool(const TEST *, const TEST*)> TestCompareType;
TEST **items;
std::sort(items, items+size, 
    [](const TEST *p1, const TEST *p2) 
    {
        if(p1->a == p2->a)
        {
            return p1->b < p2->b;
        }
        else 
        { 
            // Ooops! Forgot to put "return here"
            p1->a < p2->a;

            // This would fix it
            // return p1->a < p2->a;
        }
    });
```

but I get a crash saying "Expression: invalid comparator"

Any ideas?

Update: I was completely off base about thinking the error had something to do with using std::sort with arrays of pointers. I replaced the example code with code that was closer to what I had. Figured out that I had a typo. I didn't have a return in all cases of the comparator.

Comment: *but I get a crash saying that the compare function is no good.* What is the exact error message? (Also I hope there is more code in your actual application because `items` is not initialized. Please make an MVCE

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: The `typedef` in unneeded and not used.

Comment: Your `std::sort` line seems correct (assuming pointer con't be `nullptr`, `items` and `size` correctly initialized).

Comment: My spidey sense is tingling and telling me that the actual sort lambda you use which doesn't work (and haven't posted), tries to sort on both a _and_ b but doesn't perfectly use _strict weak ordering_. But thats obviously a guess as you haven't presented us with a MCVE.

Comment: Mike Vine -You are correct. I was so convinced it had to do with using std::sort with arrays of pointers. My ordering lambda had a dumb typo, where in one case I didn't have a return statement. Boo on me.

Answer (score 3):

When you use

```
struct
{
   int a;
   int b;
} TEST;
```

You are defining `TEST` to be a variable of an anonymous `struct` type.

And then you proceed to use `TEST` as though it were a type.

```
TEST **items;
```

Change the definition of `TEST` so it is a type.

```
struct TEST
{
   int a;
   int b;
};
```

---

Here's a demonstrative program that builds successfully but does not do anything useful.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>

struct TEST
{
   int a;
   int b;
};

void sortStuff(TEST** items, size_t size)
{
   std::sort(items, items+size,
             [](const TEST *p1, const TEST *p2) { return p1->a < p2->a; });
}

int main() {}
```